# How to map CTRL-Comma with oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, key-bindings, oh-my-zsh

I find that it would be great to map "cd .." to CTRL-Comma and maybe even traverse back down to previous sub-directories with CTRL-Period.

Is there any possible way to implement this in the oh-my-zsh conf??

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + alphabetic character, with few exceptions. According to [ASCII standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20091028133103/http://geocities.com/dtmcbride//tech/charsets/ascii.html), neither `^.` nor `^,` is a valid control character.

What you can is to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>:

```
bindkey -s '^[[1;5A' 'cd ..\n' # Ctrl + ↑
bindkey -s '^[[1;5B' 'cd -\n'  # Ctrl + ↓
```

If `^[[1;5A` and `^[[1;5B` don't work for you, you can figure to what sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> correspond by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then the desired key combination.